# discord.py after function executing twice in a row

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have a bot that is supposed to move through a queue and play songs through the voice client. After a song, it should use `check_queue` to take out the first song in the list so it can move on to the next. However, the method looks like its being run twice, meaning it takes out two songs instead of one.

```
@commands.command()
async def q(self, ctx, *, url):
    channel = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.voice_channels, name="Melodies of Arts")

    if ctx.voice_client is None:
        await channel.connect()


    def check_queue(error):
        if(len(queues[ctx.guild.id]) != 0):
            print("poppin off")
            player = queues[ctx.guild.id].pop(0)
            ctx.voice_client.play(player, after=check_queue)     

    async with ctx.typing():
        player = await YTDLSource.from_url(url, loop=self.bot.loop)

        if ctx.guild.id in queues:
            queues[ctx.guild.id].append(player)
        else:
            queues[ctx.guild.id] = [player]

        await ctx.send("Video __" + str(player.title) + "__" + " queued at **Position #" + str(len(queues[ctx.guild.id])) + "**", delete_after=15)

    if(not ctx.voice_client.is_playing()):
        print("not playing,moving on")
        ctx.voice_client.play(player, after=check_queue)
        await ctx.send('***Now playing:*** __{}__'.format(player.title), delete_after=10)
```

I made sure there weren't two instances of the bot running at once. I do not know whether or not the `after` parameter in the `play` function is being run twice, but I cannot figure this out for the life of me.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out it was my command that lists the queue that was the issue. Fixing the code related to that seemed to have solved the issue.